# KNN model with too many variables

Tags: python, pandas, knn

Let's say I have this DataFrames with 3 millions rows and 17 mil de products differents

DataFrame A (Operations)

```
id | codoper | CodProd  | valor
-------------------------------
1  | 00001   | 55       | 45000
2  | 00001   | 18       | 45000
3  | 00002   | 33       | 53000
1  | 00001   | 55       | 45000
```

I would like to apply a clustering model but if I place the products in columns it will generate a dataframe like this

```
id | codoper |valor | Product_18| Product_22| Product_33| Product_55| Product_67 | ......
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 00001   |45000 | 1         | 0         | 0         | 1         | 0          | ......
2  | 00002   |53000 | 0         | 0         | 1         | 0         | 0          | ......
```

The problem will be that to send a value to classify in the model you would have to send 17000 thousand product variables

Any idea what logic I can apply to not send so many variables?

thanks

Comment: maybe groupby function? what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Yes,I made a grouping by transactions, such as 17000 products, create 17000 columns @Giuseppe